# ptz_control on p2os_driver

Tags: ros, p2os-driver, p2os, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with the p2os_driver on a seekur_jr robot. (ROS-GROOVY, UBUNTU 12.04)
I have successfully moved the robot with the teleop_keyboard launch. (using serial port ttyS0)

But I haven't found a way to pan,tilt and zoom the PTZ camera using p2os_driver.
I've a node written by myself which publishes a PTZState msg on /ptz_control topic.
When I publish a msg on /ptz_control, the /ptz_state topic changes its values either, but the camera does not move.

Maybe the commands I am sending to /ptz_control are not being effective because the ptz port configuration is wrong.
The PTZ camera is a rvision connected to the COM4 (ttyS3) serial port.
**I would like to know what is the port the p2os_driver expects the ptz camera to be connected, and also how I could change this parameter.**

I've checked the p2os_ptz.cc and p2os.cc codes to see if I could change this parameter. It appears the ptz msgs comes from the aux serial port. If it is possible, how could I configure it to communicate with ttyS3 port?

Thank you,
Jhony Ferreira

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246421/ptz_control-on-p2os_driver/) by [Jhony Ferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/27874/jhony-ferreira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the p2os_driver sends commands to the robot controller, which would send them to a camera. This was used a long time ago and only supports some older Sony and Canon cameras.

For the RVision SEE camera you would need a separate node to control it.  The RVision SEE may support the VISCA protocol but I haven't yet found a generic ROS driver for VISCA control, unfortunately, or anything specific to the RVision SEE camera.    (If you want to see how ARIA library controls the RVision camera you can look at its source code.)

If anyone knows of an existing ROS driver for RVision or VISCA please let us know.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0